# Inserting Incremented Dates for SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, increment

I am working on updating a sign-in and sign-out log for a server (I didn't write the code myself, and I am new to SQL), and there was an issue where shifts that go past midnight do not increment the day (it will say that someone signed in at 11pm on June 30th, and then signed out at 3am on June 30th). Since all the shifts are less than 4 hours, I figured I could just set it to increment the day if the sign out time is earlier than the sign in time.

I don't know how to send in multiple statements, so I figured I could just do the following:

```
INSERT INTO Reports (MemberId,StartTime,EndTime) VALUES (6000,'2013-10-23 23:05:00',(SELECT DATE_ADD('2013-10-23 00:08:00',INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

(I'm doing this mostly in C++, so the values for dates/ID numbers are determined in the C++ program, and then printed as a ssUpdate statement to submit to the database. The above is one example of the kind of statement I am getting C++ to print out right now. Statements that don't include the DATE_ADD function work fine, so I know that is not the issue.)

When I try to do this, I get a "syntax error" statement. I would really prefer not to restructure the C code or submit multiple sql statements if there is any possible way to avoid it, because I don't exactly know how the original programmer integrated SQL and C++ and how he is submitting statements to the database.

I'm sorry if this isn't enough info, I've never asked a question on here before...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you may try

```
INSERT INTO reports
    (memberId, starttime, endtime )
SELECT 
    6000, 
    '2013-10-23 23:05:00', 
    DATE_ADD('2013-10-23 00:08:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried using a select operator like you suggested, but I get a "syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" message

Comment: I think so. It's all through microsoft access 2007. I'm sorry I don't know much about database work.

Comment: can you try to do just `SELECT DATE_ADD('2013-10-23 00:08:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY) ` to see if you get no error ?

Comment: I get this message: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'DATE_ADD('2013-10-23 00:08:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY)'